# Deleting duplicate rows from sqlite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a huge table - 36 million rows - in SQLite3. In this very large table, there are two columns:

- `hash` - text
- `d` - real

Some of the rows are duplicates. That is, both `hash` and `d` have the same values. If two hashes are identical, then so are the values of `d`. However, two identical `d`'s does not imply two identical `hash`'es.

I want to delete the duplicate rows. I don't have a primary key column.

What's the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You need a way to distinguish the rows.  Based on your comment, you could use the special [rowid column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for that.

To delete duplicates by keeping the lowest `rowid` per `(hash,d)`:

```
delete   from YourTable
where    rowid not in
         (
         select  min(rowid)
         from    YourTable
         group by
                 hash
         ,       d
         )
```

Comment: To run this on a large table you also likely want to first `CREATE INDEX YourTable_hash_d ON YourTable(hash, d)` which will speed things up dramatically as per `.expert`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the fastest would be to use the very database for it: add a new table with the same columns, but with proper constraints (a unique index on hash/real pair?), iterate through the original table and try to insert records in the new table, ignoring constraint violation errors (i.e. continue iterating when exceptions are raised).

Then delete the old table and rename the new to the old one.

Comment: Not as elegant as simply altering the table, I guess, BUT one really good thing about your approach is that you can re-run it as many times as you like without touching/destroying the source data until you're absolutely happy with the results.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution was not working for me, so I ended up doing this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_table
DROP TABLE your_table
ALTER TABLE temp_table RENAME TO your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

If adding a primary key is not an option, then one approach would be to store the duplicates DISTINCT in a temp table, delete all of the duplicated records from the existing table, and then add the records back into the original table from the temp table.

For example (written for SQL Server 2008, but the technique is the same for any database):

```
DECLARE @original AS TABLE([hash] varchar(20), [d] float)
INSERT INTO @original VALUES('A', 1)
INSERT INTO @original VALUES('A', 2)
INSERT INTO @original VALUES('A', 1)
INSERT INTO @original VALUES('B', 1)
INSERT INTO @original VALUES('C', 1)
INSERT INTO @original VALUES('C', 1)

DECLARE @temp AS TABLE([hash] varchar(20), [d] float)
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT [hash], [d] FROM @original 
GROUP BY [hash], [d]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

DELETE O
FROM @original O
JOIN @temp T ON T.[hash] = O.[hash] AND T.[d] = O.[d]

INSERT INTO @original
SELECT [hash], [d] FROM @temp

SELECT * FROM @original
```

I'm not sure if sqlite has a `ROW_NUMBER()` type function, but if it does you could also try some of the approaches listed here: [Delete duplicate records from a SQL table without a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985384/delete-duplicate-records-from-a-sql-table-without-a-primary-key)

Comment: +1, not sure if sqlite supports the `delete <alias> from <table> <alias>` syntax though