# Delete a record's duplicates but leave 1 (without Identifier)

Tags: c#, sqlite, duplicates

Let's say we have this data:

```
rc_id      phonenumber
1               0
2               0
5               1
5               3
5               3
5               3
```

and I want to delete records matching `rc_id` of 5 and `phonenumber` of 3 while keeping at least 1 of them

The final result should be:

```
rc_id      phonenumber
1               0
2               0
5               1
5               3
```

Note: **I don't want to use an unique identifier**

I'm using this statement at the moment, but I noticed this deletes all other duplicates as well.

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_data WHERE rc_id='5' AND phonenumber='3'";
```

Comment: That question does not apply to SQLite.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190541/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-sqlite-database

Comment: @xperator have you tried the above link?

Comment: @EhsanUllah I just read that and I kinda understand how it works. But the statements used in there doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. It used a `GROUP BY` which I don't know how it works. I think the OP in there wants to delete any duplicates in the entire DB

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use RowNumber() over()

```
delete from tbl_data where  Rownumber() Over(partition by rc_id, phonenumber Order by rc_id) > 1
```

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.

Comment: ahh missed that tag, sorry

Answer (score -1):

set rowcount 1
delete from tbl_data
where rc_id='5' AND phonenumber='3'

Comment: Refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444 link

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.

Comment: I didn't checked for the tag. Anyways.... I thought that the answer would be appreciated...

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_data WHERE rc_id='5' AND phonenumber='3'
                   LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM tbl_data WHERE rc_id='5' AND phonenumber='3')";
```

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.

Comment: sorry, missed the sqlite tag, too... edited answer...

Comment: I get syntax error on `LIMIT` cause.

Comment: `LIMIT` on `DELETE` is an optional extension that is not enabled by default. See EhsanUllah's link for a working solution.

Comment: The linked solution (see EhsanUllah) does not work, because here are no unique identifiers available.