# Deleting duplicate rows in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, duplicates

How to entries that have same entries?
My table player have two aspects(name, wowp_id) that duplicate. How to merge them?

I have been looking for related questions. The code below is build on the answers that I found. Process runs fine but duplicates remain. I would like to have no duplicate **names**. If there are different **wowp_id** for multiple **name** I would prefer to remove **wowp_id** and keep only one entry of **name**.

```
def sql_removeduplicates():
    con = sqlite3.connect('WOWT.sql')
    with con:    
        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM players GROUP BY name, team, wowp_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        con.commit()
        for row in rows:
            print row
```

my rows in players:

```
  (id, wowp_id, name, team)
(108, 501078041, u'prazluges', None)
(109, 507894244, u'Aidis', None)
(110, 500742127, u'Aidis', None)
(111, u'Aidis', u'Aidis', None)
(112, u'Aidis', u'Aidis', None)
(113, 500864543, u'prazluges', None)
(114, u'Aidis', u'Aidis', None)
(115, u'Aidis', u'Aidis', None)
(116, u'Aidis', u'Aidis', None)
(117, 501078041, u'satih', None)
(118, u'Aidis', u'Aidis', None)
```

Comment: Note also, that sqlite3 has a hidden ROWID column that you can use to delete duplicate rows, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190541/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-sqlite-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a unique index on the column, or define a unique constraint on the table using indexed columns.

[`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ...`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

[`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... (..., UNIQUE(col1, col2, col3), ...)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

These help prevent repetition before it arises. Links are to the SQLite documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```sql
DELETE FROM players
 WHERE id NOT IN
(
  SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM players
   GROUP BY wowp_id, name
);
```

**Note:** before proceeding with `DELETE` make sure that you have a solid backup of your data.

After deleting duplicates from your table make sure to create a `UNIQUE` constraint

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_wowp_id_name ON players(wowp_id, name);
```

Outcome after deduping:

```
|  id |   wowp_id |      name | team |
|-----|-----------|-----------|------|
| 108 | 501078041 | prazluges | None |
| 109 | 507894244 |     Aidis | None |
| 110 | 500742127 |     Aidis | None |
| 111 |     Aidis |     Aidis | None |
| 113 | 500864543 | prazluges | None |
| 117 | 501078041 |     satih | None |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5a3cb/1)** demo

Comment: What does UNIQUE constraint do? And why I need it?

Answer (score 1):

Import your results into a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/set.html) of a custom class with the contains method defined to keep what you want. Example follows:

```
class players:
   def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.playersObj.name != item.name
   # Your other methods go here
```

Then import your rows into an instance of players and write them back out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to remove duplicated WOWP_ID for the same NAME. I assume you are keeping the largest WOWP_ID for each NAME. If you have a reliable unique key such as a primary key in your table, the answer is quite simple. If you don't have such a key, you may try something like this:

```
import unittest
import sqlite3

class DaoTest(unittest.TestCase):                
    def testDeleteDuplicates(self):
        with sqlite3.connect("WOWT.sql") as conn:
            rowsToDelete = conn.execute('''
                SELECT PLAYERS.NAME, PLAYERS.TEAM, PLAYERS.WOWP_ID FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT PLAYERS.NAME, MAX(WOWP_ID) AS MAX_ID FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT WOWP_ID) AS DUP FROM PLAYERS
                        GROUP BY NAME
                        HAVING DUP > 1
                    ) DUPTABLE
                    ON PLAYERS.NAME = DUPTABLE.NAME
                    GROUP BY PLAYERS.NAME
                ) RowsToKeep
                ON PLAYERS.NAME = RowsToKeep.NAME AND PLAYERS.WOWP_ID <> MAX_ID
            ''')
            conn.executemany("DELETE FROM PLAYERS WHERE NAME = ? AND TEAM = ? AND WOWP_ID = ?", rowsToDelete)
```

Comment: This one seems a bit more complicated than other suggestions. But thank you.