# Removing Duplicate Rows based on

Tags: sqlite

I have such a database structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `tenant_counter` (
    `id`    TEXT,
    `date`  TEXT,
    `time`  TEXT,
    `date_time` TEXT,
    `sayacdeger`    REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id,date_time)
);
```

In some rows, id, date and sayacdeger occurs multiple times with all keeping their values. So I need to keep only one of them. I tried :

```
delete from tenant_counter 
where exists (
    select 1 from tenant_counter r
    where r.id = tenant_counter.id
    and r.date = tenant_counter.date
    and r.sayacdeger = tenant_counter.sayacdeger
)
```

But that deletes all duplicated rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting duplicate rows from sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8190541/608639)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROWID , and only leave those rows , which has the lowest ( min ) ROWID for given data

like this

```
delete from tenant_counter 
where exists (
    select 1 from tenant_counter r
    where r.id = tenant_counter.id
    and r.date = tenant_counter.date
    and r.sayacdeger = tenant_counter.sayacdeger
    and r.rowid < tenant_counter.rowid
)
```

with IN approach

```
DELETE FROM tenant_counter 
WHERE ROWID NOT IN ( 
    select min(rowid) from tenant_counter r 
    group by r.id,r.date,r.sayacdeger 
)
```

Comment: Can it be done with min(timestamp) as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete   from tenant_counter
where    rowid not in
         (
         select  min(rowid)
         from    tenant_counter AS r
         where r.id = tenant_counter.id
         and r.date = tenant_counter..date
         and r.sayacdeger = tenant_counter.sayacdeger
```

)