# Delete multiple rows and keep only one for each id

Tags: sqlite, delete-row

I have  table that looks like this that has two columns:

1. id
2. name

I have multiple records and some of them has the same id, I want to delete all the duplicates and only keep one id for each row.

So I have the data like this:

```
id: 1
name: Test1

id: 1
name: Test1

id: 2
name: Test1

id: 2
name: Test1

id: 2
name: Test1

id: 3
name: Test1
```

And want it to be like this instead:

```
id: 1
name: Test1

id: 2
name: Test1

id: 3
name: Test1
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190541/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-sqlite-database#8190671) answer but it returned all rows with id 1...

Comment: Find an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190541/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-sqlite-database#8190671 and fix your primary key so that it doesn't happen again.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, no it´s not a duplicate that answer returned all id´s with 1 and deleted the rest...

Comment: @RolfofSaxony and in that answer he compares two columns I only compare one. So could you please remove the duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see it working by making another table and copying into that table just the rows you want. This is a tested solution.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id,name);

INSERT INTO mytable
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    ('1','Test1'),
    ('1','Test1'),
    ('2','Test1'),
    ('2','Test1'),
    ('2','Test1'),
    ('3','Test1')

CREATE TABLE mytable2 (id,name);

INSERT INTO mytable2 
    select m2.id, m2.name 
    from mytable m2
    group by m2.id || m2.name
    having count(m2.id || m2.name) >= 1
```

Desired resultset:

```
>>> conn.execute('select * from mytable2;').fetchall()
[(u'1', u'Test1'), (u'2', u'Test1'), (u'3', u'Test1')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this only keps all id´s with id: 1 and deleted the rest.

Comment: Change `group by name` to `group by id`

Comment: @MikeSpenz: I've now provided a different solution. Let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to delete the duplicates from database, not only from output.

```
delete from mytable where ROWID not in (select ROWID from mytable group by id);

select * from mytable;
```

Output:

```
1|Test1
2|Test1
3|Test1
```

- make a table on the fly, of rowids of only one occurrence of each id
  (the part within `()`)
- delete everything which does not have one of those rowids
- select everything which remains, just for demonstration

Using SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28 18:48:43

Thanks to @bernie for making a mcve!
It is so much more efficient and more fun to work on a mcve than on a list of values.

Comment: As suggested, this does look suspiciously like the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190541/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-sqlite-database#8190671 Still +1 for proving it

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Yes and no. Yes: technically same. No: I did not get the impression that the answer was visible from point of view of OP (even with the help in a comment here) and decided to skin-tailor an answer anyway (and did so without actually looking there). Nevertheless: Credits and thanks to SO-authors of earlier comments and answers with the ROWID trick, which definitly is where I learned it. And to you for the upvote. ;-)