# delete duplicate records from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have so many duplicate records

```
SELECT ENROLMENT_NO_DATE,  COUNT(ENROLMENT_NO_DATE) AS NumOccurrences
FROM Import_Master GROUP BY ENROLMENT_NO_DATE HAVING ( COUNT(ENROLMENT_NO_DATE) > 1 )
```

I need to remove duplicate record if it is occur second time... Need to keep first or any of one record. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: @João No one... but need ENROLMENT_NO_DATE as unique in table

Comment: There are many posts related to this topic.Please go through these links.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286843/how-to-keep-only-one-row-of-a-table-removing-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CTE to perform this task:

```
;with cte as
(
  select ENROLMENT_NO_DATE, 
    row_number() over(partition by ENROLMENT_NO_DATE order by ENROLMENT_NO_DATE) rn
  from Import_Master
) 
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

See [SQL Fddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0aec6/10)

Comment: @bluefeet I've always thought of CTEs as temp tables, it seems wrongly, so I'm surprised that deleting from CTE, deletes from source.

Answer (score 1):

One method could be to create a secondary, temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE Import_Master_Deduped AS SELECT * FROM Import_Master WHERE FALSE;
```

This will create an empty table with identical structure to Import_Master. Now impose uniqueness on the new table with an index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Import_Master_Ndx ON Import_Master_Deduped(ENROLMENT_NO_DATE);
```

Finally copy the table with duplicated records inside with INSERT IGNORE, so that duplicated records will not get inserted:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Import_Master_Deduped SELECT * FROM Import_Master;
```

At this point, after checking everything is OK, you can rename the two tables swapping their names (this will lose any old indexes), or TRUNCATE the Import_Master table and copy back the deduped records from the new table into the old.

In the second case, recreate the UNIQUE constraint on the old table to avoid further duplicates; in the first, recreate any old indexes on the new table.

Finally, you remove the table you don't need anymore.