# How to remove the duplicate rows by using single column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to remove duplicate rows in my table. There is a unique column `dataframeid`. According to the `dataframeid`, I want to remove duplicate records

Same records shows up 5 times.

Table - `OLTMS_5B0395`

Sample data

```
id  DataFrameId DId OT  WT  AT  RC  YC  BC  RV  YV  BV  Oa  Aa  Gt  G   M   P   S   Ot  O   FCNT    RSSI    SF  SNR Rec
2391    1525345797494   4   0   0   35  338 333 664 245 244 245 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1243    -92 12  -18 2018-03-05 16:39:00
2459    1525345797494   4   0   0   35  338 333 664 245 244 245 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1243    -92 12  -18 2018-03-05 16:39:00
2282    1525345797494   4   0   0   35  338 333 664 245 244 245 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1243    -92 12  -18 2018-03-05 16:39:00
2300    1525345797494   4   0   0   35  338 333 664 245 244 245 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1243    -92 12  -18 2018-03-05 16:39:00
2338    1525345797494   4   0   0   35  338 333 664 245 244 245 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1243    -92 12  -18 2018-03-05 16:39:00
```

Expected output

```
 2282   1525345797494   4   0   0   35  338 333 664 245 244 245 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1243    -92 12  -18 2018-03-05 16:39:00
```

id that can be anything but there shouldn't be any duplicate records.

Comment: Which columns do you want to remove?    Or do you mean "duplicate rows"?   Also, what do you mean by "remove"?   Delete them from the table, or just exclude them in a query?

Comment: Everything except the id column has the same value. What would be the output from your sample data?

Comment: sorry i want to remove the duplicate rows.

Comment: Define duplicate? There are zero duplicate rows in your sample data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep only one row of a table, removing duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286843/how-to-keep-only-one-row-of-a-table-removing-duplicate-rows)

Comment: id is just serial number that we are not inserting . except serial no. all are duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

As per o/p all columns have duplicate values so, you can use `row_number()` function

```
delete t from (
     select *,
            row_number() over (partition by DataFrameId,. . . order by id) Seq 
     from OLTMS_5B0395
) t
where Seq > 1;
```

Be aware with order by clause in `row_number()` function, include column in `partition by` clause where you got the duplicate values

Comment: not all columns are duplicates there is id column which is not duplicate.

Comment: i tried the above query , still have duplicate rows

Comment: This solution will treat every row with a duplicate DataFrameID as a duplicate, even if all the other columns are different.

Comment: Please have a look at the following blog post - this should help https://thesqlserverdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/03/deleting-duplicate-records-from-table.html?view=magazine