# removing duplicate entries in sqlite3 database in a rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, duplicates

I have a sqlite3 database in a rails app. It contains amongst others these columns:
name, telephone, latitude, longitude.

These are all strings. These correspond to businesses. I noticed that many entries in the database are duplicates.

How do I remove these from my rails database? Do I need to write SQL or is there a function in rails that takes in column names and removes entries that have similar values in those columns.

If SQL is the best way, how should my query look like.

I tried the following query but my database browser crashed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM listings L1, listings L2
WHERE L1.name = L2.name
AND L1.telephone = L2.telephone
```

EDIT: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043488/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-a-table/1043505#1043505) post helpful. But still looking for a solution thats airtight.

Comment: Database browser may crash for another reason. Query looks ok, but you may try changing select to `L1.* L2.*` and adding `L1.id != L2.id` to `WHERE`

Comment: here is the query:----->SELECT * FROM listings L1, listings L2 
WHERE L1.* = L2.* 
AND L1.id  !=  L2.id------>Gives error near "*": syntax error

Comment: You cannot write `WHERE L1.* = L2.*`. I meant change **what** you select from `*` to `L1.*, L2.*`, not `WHERE` condition.