# Delete duplicate rows from DB table

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)
>   [Deleting duplicate rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043488/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-a-table)

Here's my case

I have a table named result who look like this

```
Id  Valeur   IdUtilisateur     Date      IdUnit    IdMea   IdAnalyte
1   0.440     patlach01    2012-01-02      2      39258    2541
2   0.440     patlach01    2012-01-02      2      39258    2541
3   0.440     patlach01    2012-01-02      2      39258    2541
```

As you see I have similar rows but different `id` (Identity set to yes so `id` increase auto)

I want to delete unneeded rows but keep only 1 sample

`IdUnit`, `IdMea`, `IdAnalyte` are fk for other tables

How can I do this?

And I would like to make it for all others case (yes the bd is a mess,a LOT of duplicates) so I want to be "generic' and do the job in 1 operation (if possible)

Sorry if I'm not clear enough,this is my first post here!!!!

Comment: If 'id' is an identity column, why do all rows show the same value for 'id'?  Was 'id' set explicitly? Or do you mean the original data table had an identity column that was copied over with duplicates to the 'result' table?

Answer (score 2):

In **MYSQL** you can use like this:

```
DELETE a FROM table a, table b 
WHERE a.id > b.id 
AND a.IdUtilisateur = b.IdUtilisateur
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT MIN(a.id) FROM table a 
GROUP BY a.IdUtilisateur) b)
```

***Note:*** table is the name of your table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep it really help!!!!  thanks for your fast answer!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT A.RowId FROM
 (SELECT Id,MAX(ID) AS RowId
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY ID
 ) A
);
```

Assuming this is MYSQL, I gave the solution.

P.S: The ID in the where clause is ROWID which we use in MYSQL.

Comment: Thanks to all!!  I take a bit of all your tips and it work exactly as I need.   I only need to drop constraint,execute delete then add constraint.   I'll work tomorrow on deleting child ref on other tabs.