# MySQL: What is the safest way to remove duplicate rows from a MySQL TABLE?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a MySQL TABLE. It contains mailing addresses we get from a data feed. But there are no customer records for the mailing addresses, so I don't have an easy way to match a customer record as a key to see if it exists already in the master TABLE. So I've decided to have the new daily data feed added to the master TABLE and then remove duplicates.

What is the safest way to remove duplicates? Obviously, I want to ignore the ID column field. But how do I do this for the following fields:

```
company_name
contact_name
address1
address2
address3
city
state
zipcode
phone_number
email_address
```

What if I rebuild the MySQL TABLE to include ALTER TABLE with UNIQUE KEY, would that be safe? For example:

```
ALTER TABLE people ADD UNIQUE KEY (company_name,contact_name,address1,address2,address3,city,state,zipcode,phone_number,email_address)
```

Would the above safely prevent duplicated records from being INSERTed to begin with?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give more sample records?

Comment: Wloud you define what you mean by duplicate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816863/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-duplicate-values-from-mysql-table try this

Comment: You can use SELECT DISTINCT Statement

Comment: @bksiA duplicate is a row that contains the fields/columns I mentioned that each contain the exact same data.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest Query you can use 
Choose Max or min based on your requirement.

```
DELETE
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DuplicateColumn1, DuplicateColumn2, DuplicateColumn3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please look at my added example using ALTER TABLE people ADD UNIQUE KEY. I'd be interested to know what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

DELETE a FROM test a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id, company_name, contact_name, address1, address2, address3, city, state, zipcode, phone_number, email_address
    FROM test
    GROUP BY company_name, contact_name, address1, address2, address3, city, state, zipcode, phone_number, email_address
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.company_name = b.company_name AND a.contact_name = b.contact_name AND a.address1 = b.address1 AND a.address2 = b.address2 AND a.address3 = b.address3 AND a.city = b.city AND a.state = b.state AND a.zipcode = b.zipcode AND a.phone_number = b.phone_number AND a.email_address = b.email_address
WHERE b.id IS NULL