# Remove Common Data In Access Table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, duplicates

I'm using an Access Database and have the following question:

**How is it possible to remove entire rows based on certain columns?**

For example I have the following table:

```
Id | Name |   Desc  | Contact No. | 
1  | XYZ  | bla bla | 123456      | 
2  | ABC  | bla bla | 123456      |
3  | TUV  | hmmmmm  | 123456      |
4  | XYZ  | bla bla | 123456      |
```

I want to remove all lines of data which have duplicate information, so in this case, rows 1 & 4. The only issue of course, is the Id, which makes the overall row unique....

How would I go about removing this? Is there some SQL code that can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An autojoin for detecting the duplicate:

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE Id IN
(
    SELECT t1.Id
    FROM Table t1
        INNER JOIN join Table t2
            ON t1.Name = t2.Name
            AND t1.[Desc] = t2.[Desc]
            AND t1.Contact = t2.Contact 
)
```

If you want to keep only one row for each duplicate, look this question : [Deleting duplicate rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043488/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-a-table)

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE Id NOT IN
(
    SELECT MIN(Id)
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Name, [Desc], Contact
)
```

Comment: I have no access database under my hand. I know Access has a lot of limitations, but the two queries are pretty standard.

Comment: Typing in this code causes access to complain "Syntax Error in Query Expression" - the query executes when removing the group by.

Comment: using `GROUP BY [Name], [Desc], Contact` would fix that

Answer (score 2):

If you need to delete all rows that have a duplicate, you could use this Ms-Access SQL query:

```
DELETE tbl.Id
FROM tbl
WHERE (((tbl.Id) In (SELECT tbl.Id
  FROM
    (SELECT [Name], [Desc], [Contact]
     FROM tbl
     GROUP BY [Name], [Desc], [Contact]
     HAVING COUNT(*)>1)  AS [t1]
  INNER JOIN tbl
  ON ([t1].Contact = tbl.Contact)
     AND ([t1].[Desc] = tbl.[Desc])
     AND ([t1].[Name] = tbl.[Name]))));
```

To keep just the first duplicate you could use this:

```
DELETE tbl.Id
FROM tbl
WHERE (tbl.Id) Not In (SELECT Min(tbl.Id) AS MinId
FROM tbl
GROUP BY tbl.[Name], tbl.[Desc], tbl.[Contact]);
```

Comment: It complains when adding the Group By

Comment: @user559142 wrong copy&paste i'm sorry...:) now it should be okay, it works on my database