# DELETE query giving "operand should contain 1 column" error

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-delete

I need to delete some specific duplicates from my database. I've created a query that finds the records I need, but when running it as a subquery I get the error "`operand should contain 1 column`" I don't know how to get the specific information I need while only choosing a single column.

The query is :

```
delete
from products
where id in (SELECT *
FROM products
GROUP BY part_number
 HAVING count(*) > 1 and manufacturer_id="4146"
)
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Replace `select * ` with `select id_column`. And please don't put numbers into double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, this gives the response : Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'products' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1):

In your sub query you need to select id one column

```
delete
from products
where id IN (SELECT id
FROM products
WHERE manufacturer_id="4146" 
GROUP BY part_number
 HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Also getting id from same table will give you another  error *Can't specify target table* you need to provide new alias to your subquery

```
delete
from products
where id IN 
(SELECT t.id FROM (
(SELECT id
FROM products
WHERE manufacturer_id="4146" 
GROUP BY part_number
 HAVING count(*) > 1 ) t
)
```

Comment: This gives the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'manufacturer_id' in 'having clause'

Comment: Thanks for your help @M Khalid Junaid. The problem here is that the subquery pulls an empty set. There will not be any matching IDs in the products table. Maybe if I write it out in plain english what I am trying to accomplish. First I want to get all the parts that have a count more than 1 ... of those parts, I only want to delete those which have the manufacturer ID 4146.  So I would write these two queries like : `Select part_number from products where count(part_number) > 1` and of that set `select part_number where manufacturer id='4146'` but how to bundle them into a delete query?

Comment: @user116694 refer to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043488/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-a-table?rq=1)